# How to publish a web service from within a Java Desktop Application

Tags: java, web-services, desktop-application

What I'm trying to do is write a Selenium Webdriver Recorder that will work with any supported browser without needing a browser plugin. I need to be able to communicate back to my Java Desktop Application the actions performed in the browser, however, as I cannot capture browser events via Webdriver I cannot rely on just returning the info via javaScriptExecutor.  Therefore I'm looking at trying to host a Java Web Service within my application and preferably only have it listening during recording.

How can I implement an adhoc Web Service like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a embedded jetty server that handles websocket request from the browser. For example: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.0.v20150612/jetty-websocket-server-api.html

Comment: Thanks Marco that looks like a way forwards.  I had also been looking at Java's built in Werbserver com.sun.net.httpserver